# MYSql Select user if other user found

Tags: mysql

I have a query like

```
SELECT 
    pf.id, pf.forwhom, pf.body,
    u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email

FROM prayerfeed pf 
    JOIN users u ON pf.user_id=u.id

WHERE pf.id=100;
```

And this returns the feed item pf that I want as well as the user that posted that item.

What I also need is the users name that responded to that feed item and I know their id, lets call it 2.

This doesn't work but it might explain what I need.

```
SELECT 
    pf.id, pf.forwhom, pf.body,
    u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email,
    ru.firstname, ru.lastname
FROM prayerfeed pf 
    JOIN users u ON pf.user_id=u.id
    SELECT FROM users ru WHERE id=2 
WHERE pf.id=834;
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: You do a second join exactly as the previous one for users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional `JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    pf.id, pf.forwhom, pf.body,
    u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email,
    u2.firstname, u2.lastname, u2.email

FROM prayerfeed pf 
    JOIN users u ON pf.user_id=u.id

    JOIN users u2 ON u2.id = 2

WHERE pf.id=100;
```

You can simply use the `ON` clause to filter the user that responded to the feed item, using the already known `id` value.

Comment: Yup that is it. I could swear I tried that. So simple but now I don't know what I did try and got wrong. 

Thanks

Comment: @Shadow do you see a better way?

Comment: @PaulNeale You can alternatively use a `CROSS JOIN`, but I doubt if this makes any difference performance-wise.

Comment: Don't think that I have ever seen that option. Will look deeper at it even if it doesn't change anything.